# how to add or remove application shortcuts from mac launchpad when application is not in /Applications directory

Tags: macos

I installed some jetbrains applications using the JetBrains Toolbox and I see that the applications appear in the mac launchpad but the application does not exist in the /Applications folder.
This is also true for Applications installed in google chrome that some way show up in the mac launchpad
How are these applications registered with the launchpad so that they show up and how can I create or remove these shortcuts?

Comment: Ever find an answer?

Comment: I did find out that at least with Chrome apps there is an Applications folder under your user folder where chrome apps are installed.

$HOME/Applications

Comment: The Launchpad shortcuts are in $HOME/Applications like Chrome